# How to define a common module logging shared among others module

Tags: ruby, logging, module

I am developing a script with a big main function, which I have split in several modules.
What I need is to have access to the log functionality from all of them, this means that the log file has to be opened only once, and the access be shared.

This is what I have:

```
require 'module_1'
require 'module_2'
require 'module_3'

module Main
 Module_1.Function_startup()
 Module_2.Function_configuration()
 Module_3.Function_self_test()
end
```

Here is the dirty module for the logger I need available in all the other modules.
Ideally I would like to call it as "logger.error", where "logger" returns the instance of the logger, and "error" is the function call on rlogger as rlogger.error.

```
require 'logger'

module Logging
  @rlogger = nil

    def init_logger
      if @rlogger.nil?
        puts "initializing logger"
        file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'checker.log')
        open_mode = File::TRUNC # or File::APPEND
        file = File.open(file_path, File::WRONLY | open_mode)

        @rlogger = Logger.new(file)
        @rlogger.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

        @rlogger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
          con_msg = ""
          if msg.match("ERROR:")
            con_msg = msg.color(:red)
          elsif msg.match("OK!")
            con_msg = msg.color(:green)
          else
            con_msg = msg
          end
          puts ">>>#{con_msg}"
          # notice that the colors introduce extra non-printable characters
          # which are not nice in the log file.
          "#{datetime}: #{msg}\n"
        end

        # Here is the first log entry
        @rlogger.info('Initialize') {"#{Time.new.strftime("%H-%M-%S")}: Checker v#{@version}"}
      end
    end

    # returns the logger
    def logger
      if @rlogger.nil?
        puts "requesting nil rlogger"
      end
      @rlogger
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after require you can add this piece of code

```
$FILE_LOG = Logging.create_log(File.expand_path('LoggingFile.log'), Logger::DEBUG)
```

Explanation of the above line : It is calling a function in Logging Module, to create File , Level of Logging is debug.

Below is the piece of code for Module

```
module Logging
  def self.create_log(output_location level)
    log = Logger.new(output_location, 'weekly').tap do |l|
      next unless l

      l.level = level

      l.progname = File.basename($0)

      l.datetime_format = DateTime.iso8601

      l.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg| "#{severity}: #{datetime} - (#{progname}) : #{msg}\n" }
    end

    log.level = level if level < log.level
    log
  end


  def self.log(msg, level)
    # Here I am just logging only FATAL and DEBUG, similarly you can add in different level of logs
    if level == :FATAL
      $FILE_LOG.fatal(msg)
    elsif level == :DEBUG
      $FILE_LOG.debug(msg)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in Every method every Ruby file, we can use this logging as follows

```
Logging.log("Message",:FATAL)
```